# Logical 'and' with object and value in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In the book 'Functional javascript' by Michael Fogus, I faced with one expression that I still can't undrestand.
Here is the function:

```
function defaults(d){
  return function(o, k){
    var val = fnull(_.identity, d[k]);
    return o && val(o[k]);
  }
}
```

where

```
function fnull(fun /*, defaults*/){
  var defaults = _.rest(arguments);
  return function(/* args */){
    var args = _.map(arguments, function(e, i){
      return existy(e)?e : defaults[i];
    });
    return fun.apply(null, args);
  };
};

function existy(x){return x != null}
```

(underscore is the object of Underscore.js library)
and the example of use:

```
function doSomething(config){
  var lookup = defaults({critical:108});
  return lookup(config, 'critical');
}

doSomething({critical: 9});
//=> 9
doSomething({});
//=> 108
```

I've recreated exapmle in node.js and it works fine, but I wonder why is the logical 'and' in the return line of 'default' function?

```
return o && val(o[k]);
```

What is the point of doing that? I checked the exapmle with

```
return val(o[k]);
```

and it also worked well. 
It's hard to believe that this is just a mistake...

Comment: It's short circuit used in a smart way. There are many more defensive JS techniques like that. I posted a long version of things I find most useful for you to read on one spot. It's a bit long, but if you invest time, your code iwill benefit in speed, stability or you can simply save a couple of lines of code with a smart shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical and will make sure the second part is only evaluated if the first part is true. If `o` does not evaluate to true, the expression returns false. Otherwise, it returns `val(o[k])`.

This is used as a quick check to see if o is not false / null / undefined.

Comment: So it is only a quick check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
return o && val(o[k])
```

mean that if "o" is TRUE it will return "val(o[k])"

given "expr1 && expr2":

Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

Comment: "Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2." what this means?

Comment: if expr1 ( your "o") is castable to boolean false return false (then will not return expr2 (your "val(o[k])" ), otherwise returns expr2  (your "val(o[k])" )

Answer (score 0):

That is smart usage of something called short "short-circuiting" in logical expressions.

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested
> for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> `false && (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to false.
>
> `true ||(anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to true.

The rules of logic guarantee that these evaluations are always correct. Note that **the `(anything)` part of the above expressions is not evaluated** (meaning not ran at all), so any side effects of doing so do not take effect. **There are also benefits to it.**

Usage:

- Make your expressions evaluate faster by putting something easily calculable or likely to be true/fail at leftmost position in expression.
- For example `parOfExpressionLikelyToBeTrue && (rest of expression)` will in most cases not even calculate the other part of expression. Same goes for `parOfExpressionLikelyToBeTrue || (rest of espression)`.
- Same can be used if something is very time consuming to calculate, you push it as far back to the right in expression. For example `(rest of the expression) && ThisCostsALotOfTime` or  `(rest of the expression) || ThisCostsALotOfTime`. Here when first parts of expression short-circuit you save time on your time consuming part.
- Short circuit existence evaluation. Lets say you need to check if your object's property pr is 3? What would you do? `obj.pr === 3`? Yes and no. What if property is missing? It's fine you will get undefined and that is not === 3. But what if object is not there. You will get trying to read pr of undefined error. **You can use short-circuit logic here to you benefit by being defensive** and writing the expression as if `(obj || obj.pr === 3)`. This ensures there are no errors, only true and false.
- Short circuit initialization. Let's say you wanna say variable a is b. But b might be undefined. And you wanna your variable to have a default. You could write a=b and then check if a is undefined and set it to default or you can be clever and write it as `a = b || 3`. This way a is b or if be is undefined it's 3. Ofc, you can use this for late initialization as well `a = a || 3`.
- Making sure object for function exists before trying to run function. Same as before mentioned with properties you might wanna test if object containing the function exists before running the function. Let's say you got object obj and function fn as it's property. You might call that function like `obj.fn()`. It's fine, but if obj is undefined you will get an error. Being defensive you might wanna write: `obj && obj.fn()`.
- Running the function only if there is one. Since functions in JS can be passed to other functions you can not be sure at run time it's there. Being defensive you might wanna run your function as (typeof passedFunction === "function" && passedFunction() instead just passedFunction() which my produce an error.
- other smart things like guardian expressions etc which are complicated and too many to for me to remember all and you should avoid them anyway for better code readability.